# Image shifts to the left on page load

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why my picture shifts to the left. If I refresh the page using `CTRL+F5` the picture is centered, exactly where I want it to be when the page loads.

[my picture goes left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV3rT.png)

My HTML

```
<section id="showcase">
   <div id="container">
       <img src="billedarkiv/eaceramideprice.jpg" width="915" height="350">
   </div>
</section>
```

And my css

```
#container {
    width: 915px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#showcase {
   margin-top: 0px;  
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: i asked a friend of my, who says the problem do not appear in his browser windwos edge, i am using chrome..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried text center alignement?

```
#container {
    width: 915px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Not working .. 

see -> www.dagenshug.dk :O! 
But now all text is of course center, i use the container on all the boxes

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS to center the image inside the container.

```
#showcase #container {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to do what ppollono's solution does-- put the text-align on the container, rather than the image.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's right. Sorry, my mistake. I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I have added your code to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/havvznn1/) to see what is happening.
The image is centered in the window as expected.

I believe you may have an un-closed html tag somewhere in the code above the showcase.

You should use an [HTML validator service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to verify the integrity of your code.

Also I would recommend you use class names instead of using IDs in your html. IDs should only be used for unique elements in the document.

For example:

```
<section class="showcase">
   <div class="container">
       <img src="billedarkiv/eaceramideprice.jpg" width="915" height="350">
   </div>
</section>
```

and also in the css:

```
.container {
    width: 915px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.showcase {
   margin-top: 0px;  
}
```

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dagenshug.dk%2F <- This is cool! Thanks for that m8, i try change all to class now then. but the problems, happens when you refresh the page, if i hit the CTRL+F5 then it centers

Comment: I have changed everything to class, now it just stay's left :O!

Comment: Changing everything to class didn't solve the problem .. :/

Comment: You will also need to update the CSS to target the classes instead of IDs also. Classes use a `.` while IDs use a `#`

Answer (score 0):

I have changed

from container to pic-container and added text-align: center;

now it works :S .. that's wird!

```
.pic-container {
text-align: center;
```

}

and

```
<section id="showcase">
        <div class="pic-container">
            <img src="billedarkiv/eaceramideprice.jpg" width="915" height="350">
        </div>
    </section>
```

Anyone have a solution to that ? :O